# How to put a space between two characters in an Input given by the user?Where is my mistake??(I am a beginner

Tags: python

```
# Read an integer:
a = int(input())
# Print a value:
print(a[0] + " " + a[1])
```

As you can see that I am trying to put a space using a string but I am having an error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You can't access the digits in an integer by using an index. You need a string for that. If you leave out the call to `int` everything will work fine.

Comment: don't convert the input to integer `a = input()` then `print(a[0] + " " + a[1])`

Comment: Thank you Matthias and deadshot I was stuck with this for 2 days..